# How to implement a WTForms solution when selecting Foreign Key values in SQLAlchemy for an admin panel?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, wtforms

I am new to sqlalchemy. I am creating an admin panel for a service. Faced with the fact that when creating an object, you need to select the necessary values from the Foreign Key. But if I use the standard admin panel, all values ​​are displayed in the select and there is no search for them. Searching for information.

I came to the conclusion that it is necessary to implement using wtforms. But I can't find how to implement it correctly. Help me please. Here is an example of my non-working code:

```py
import wtforms.widgets
from sqladmin import ModelAdmin, widgets
from wtforms import Form, SearchField
from amonitor.admin.base import ModelAdminBase
from amonitor.models.amonitor.entity.double_platforms_in_app import DoubleApps


class MyForm(Form):
    app_id = SearchField('app_id')


class AdminDoublePlatformsApp(ModelAdminBase, model=DoubleApps):
    name = "Приложение с двойными платформами"
    name_plural = "Приложения с двойными платформами"
    column_exclude_list = [DoubleApps.id]
    column_searchable_list = [DoubleApps.app]
    form_columns = [MyForm]
```